# Geometric interpretation of vector and transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, intuition, geometric-interpretation

$v^Tv$ is the dot product of a vector with itself, which is just its norm squared, an intuitive geometric quantity.

Is there something to be said about $vv^T$? Is there some kind of relationship between this matrix and some geometric object the way the cross product relates to the area of the parallelogram for example?

Comment: Yes, there is. It's a projection. $v v^\intercal$ represents the outer product of $v$

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom 3x1 by 1x3 is perfectly valid

Comment: If you want to know from a perpective of the space spanned by the matrix generated by that product, it span a one dimensional vector space with a unique vector basis, which is $v$.

Comment: My mistake. Removedm y comment now. Good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary vector $\boldsymbol{a}$ and a unit vector $\boldsymbol{v}$.

Then $\boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{a} = \boldsymbol{v}^\intercal \boldsymbol{a}$ is the component of $\boldsymbol{a}$ along $\boldsymbol{v}$.

More specifically the projection of $\boldsymbol{a}$ parallel to $\boldsymbol{v}$

$$ \boldsymbol{a}_\parallel = \boldsymbol{v} \left( \boldsymbol{v}^\intercal \boldsymbol{a} \right)$$

The above can be viewed as a matrix/vector operation

$$ \boldsymbol{a}_\parallel = [ \boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{v}^\intercal] \boldsymbol{a} $$

where $[\boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{v}^\intercal] = \boldsymbol{v} \odot \boldsymbol{v}$ is the outer product of $\boldsymbol{v}$ with itself and results in a $n\times n$ matrix.

The interpretation is that $[\boldsymbol{v} \boldsymbol{v}^\intercal]$ projects any arbitrary vector $\boldsymbol{a}$ along $\boldsymbol{v}$

Comment: Is there a scaling factor involved? $v.a$ is only the component if $v$ is unitary right? otherwise it's a scaled version of the component.

Comment: Alo when we say outer product, is this related to the outer product in exterior algebra? The wedge?

Comment: @Makogan, for your two questions, the first is yes, the second is no. $a_\Vert$ is a decomposition of $v$ taking with a unitary vector, because the factor you are talking is the norm of $v$. For the second, the wedge product of a set of vectors is related to the determinat of a matrix formed by thoose vectors. An outer product has determinant equal to $0$, because span a one dimentional and a determinant of $2\times2$ matrix gives a factor of the transformatión of area

Comment: @Makogan - I stated that $\boldsymbol{v}$ is a **unit** vector. For a general vector, yes you need to scale by dividing by $\| \boldsymbol{v} \|^2$

Comment: @Makogan - the outer product of a $n$-vector and an $m$ vector is a $n×m$ matrix where each element is $ a \odot b = \{ a_i b_j \}$